# TaskStackBack different behaviour on Android 4.4

Tags: android

I detected a problem on Android 4.4 with following code:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Ac2.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Ac1.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    stackBuilder.startActivities();
```

Precoditions: 
1. Ac1 does not declare a parent activity in the manifest
2. Ac1 is the main activity in the manifest where the app starts
3. Ac1 manifest properties have following: 
   - **android:taskAffinity=""**

Expected behaviour: Activity Ac2 is opened and when navigating up activity Ac1 is opened.

Actual behaviour till Android 4.3: Activity Ac2 is opened and when navigating up activity Ac1 is opened.
Actual behaviour on Android 4.4: Activity Ac2 is opened and when navigating up the Android Home Screen is shown.

Condition: Ac1 declares a parent activity "Ac0"
Actual behaviour on Android 4.4: Activity Ac2 is opened and when navigating up Ac0 is opened.